# Casting to protocol and using value?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Basically the issue is the RawRepresentable part of the code, I need to be able to get the value of it, but because I need to cast to a protocol it doesn't allow me to use the rawValue. Any workaround for this?

```
public protocol Serializable {
    func dictionary() -> [String: Any]
}

extension Serializable {
    func dictionary() -> [String: Any] {
        var result = [String: Any]()
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        for child in mirror.children {
            guard let label = child.label else { continue }

            switch child.value {
            case let serializable as Serializable:
                result[label] = serializable.dictionary()

            // Compile error here
            case let rawRepresentable as RawRepresentable:
                result[label] = rawRepresentable.rawValue

            default:
                result[label] = child.value
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be able to add an extension method on RawRepresentable that takes the dictionary as an inout and puts rawValue in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this comes down to issues trying to use an associatedType outside of the enum.

I fixed it like this:

```
public protocol Serializable {
    func dictionary() -> [String: Any]
}

extension Serializable {
    func dictionary() -> [String: Any] {
        var result = [String: Any]()
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        for child in mirror.children {
            guard let label = child.label else { continue }

            switch child.value {
            case let serializable as Serializable:
                result[label] = serializable.dictionary()

            case let rawRepresentable as RawRepresentable:
                let value = rawRepresentable.getValueAsAny()
                result[label] = value

            default:
                result[label] = child.value
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}

extension RawRepresentable {
    func getValueAsAny() -> Any {
        return rawValue as Any
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks this works, unless I find a cleaner solution without the new extension I'll mark this as answer

Comment: How did you compile this code? I got `Protocol 'RawRepresentable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`